Redirecting a python application with nginx
There is a domain named demo_test and I have configured it for Nginx on mac machine. If I start Tomcat and Java application in the container on that machine and add the ip and port of that process to nginx.conf and restart it, I get access as demo_test.arc.com/JPetStore. Can be done.
Similarly, I started the python application in the container and configured it in the nginx.conf file and restarted it. Then if i access it as demo_test.arc.com/login, you get a white blank page, but if i access it in the browser with the ip and port 3000 on the machine running the container, it works fine.
I already tried configuring upstream and location under nginx.conf file and restarting nginx but it didn't work.
Nginx.conf file:

upstream login {
                ip_hash;
                server 192.168.2.3:3000;
        }

location /login {
            proxy_pass http://login;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

           #  Handle errors for /home
            error_page 404 500 502 503 504 /genie.html;
        }

